# how to join excel column names with data frame headers in python?

Tags: python, excel, dataframe

I have an example data frame like:

```
adf = [['A', 'C', 'G'],['cat','dog','swine'],['black','ginger','pink']]`
pdf = pd.DataFrame.from_records(adf[1:], columns = adf[0])

Out[375]: 
       A       C      G
0    cat     dog  swine
1  black  ginger   pink
```

I need to save it into Excel worksheet but with regards of which Excel columns I want to write. Namely, I need something like join my column names from `pdf` with those in Excel to be exactly the same.

The following solution doesn't save in proper columns but from left to right:

```
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('map_df.xlsx')
ws = workbook.worksheets[0]

for r in dataframe_to_rows(pdf, index=False, header=False):
    ws.append(r)
workbook.save("appended.xlsx")
```

Notice, I load an existing workbook. I has headers in first row so I write data headless.

I'm asking about the method to map columns with each other by headers without writing it manually, deleting empty, etc. because I have real huge data. So that cat comes to column `A`, swine to `G`, and `B` or `D` should not be filled.

Examples:

[image]

Comment: Please give a concrete example of the excel file or dataframe you expect out given this input

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't super sure that you meant u needed to map the columns via the column names, which needed to be read from the file, 
You would need to create a dict of appropriate columns to map, and then write the values in after you find column number, or just write the values in according to the column names of your pandas DataFrame.

But for either, you cannot use append and would need to iterate through each value of the 'r'.

**First Version (With Mapping)**

```
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('map_df.xlsx')
ws = workbook.worksheets[0]

headers = worksheet.rows[1] # Assuming your header is in the first row

header_map = {
    col: cell.column for cell in headers if cell.value.isin(pdf.columns)
}

start_row = 1    
for r in dataframe_to_rows(pdf, index=False, header=False):
    for i, (col_name, v) in enumerate(zip(pdf.columns, r)):
        coln = header_map[col_name]
        ws['{coln}{i}'.format(coln=coln, i=i + start_row)].value = v
```

**Second Version (Straight from Header)**

```
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('map_df.xlsx')
ws = workbook.worksheets[0]

start_row = 1
for r in dataframe_to_rows(pdf, index=False, header=False):
    for i, (col_name, v) in enumerate(zip(pdf.columns, r)):
        ws['{coln}{i}'.format(coln=col_name, i=i + start_row)].value = v
```

Comment: Yes. Your both versions are good. I've done already very similar approach. I wonder if it's optimal in terms of speed. It works quite slow. Maybe it's the case Python is overall slow on my computer (apart from R for example)

Comment: It depends on what you are doing this for, but another option if you can forgo the already written header is to just map and pad your DataFrame with columns of all 'nan's since they won't show up, and then just save it using the `DataFrame.to_excel(...)` function. It is way faster but you cannot do that into a sheet and retain what is already in the sheet. 


This would also work with the `ws.append` and will save you some time with the dictionary lookup in every row, but append is not fundamentally that much faster and depending how many columns you have, may not save you that much time.

Comment: How to map with two headers? As in the first two lines are both the headers? Or in fact as the df I have has the same headers as the second row of the workbook, it might work! I will give it a go

Answer (score 0):

I've made something like this:

```
last_row = worksheet.max_row
for j in range(len(df.columns)):
    for i in range(len(df)):
        worksheet['%s%d' % (df.columns.values[j], last_row+1+i)] = df.iloc[i,j]
```

where `df` is pandas DataFrame structure of all columns I want to have in Excel. So it puts (as it's in df) for example A, C, G and B or D leaves empty (according to Excel pure column names, if you have this setting from A to XEC or something like this)

I'm not super satisfied because it's slower than save whole sheet at once.